# Semantical Error Class 'Blog' is not defined Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I have this code :

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Blog;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
     */
    public function index()
    { 
        $entityManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $blog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class);
        $dql = "SELECT id, name  FROM Blog";
        $query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                           ->setFirstResult(0)
                           ->setMaxResults(100);

        $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

        $c = count($paginator);
        foreach ($paginator as $post) {
            echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
        }

        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
            'blog' =>$blog,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But when i run it it gives me

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 22 near 'Blog': Error: Class 'Blog' is
>   not defined.
>   I also tried put

```
 $dql = "SELECT id, name  FROM App\Entity\Blog:Blog";
```

But in this way it gives me

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 37: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got ':Blog'

I dont know what to do. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct DQL query should look something like this:

```
SELECT blog.id, blog.name FROM App\Entity\Blog blog
```

The [DQL documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#title.1.2.1) should help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to S4 and refactoring code, I encountered the same issue, but was able to identify the root cause.

My code looked like this

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $select = "SELECT u";
    $from = " FROM App\Vk\UsrBundle\Entity\vUser u";   // <- Note the fully qualified path to the class definition.
    $join = "";
    $where = " WHERE u.username = '$username'";

    $query_string = $select . $from . $join . $where;
    $query = $this->em->createQuery($query_string);
    dump($query); die();                                // <- Dump $query to check how it looks
    $v_user = $query->getResult()[0];       

    if (isset($v_user))
        return $v_user;

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
    );
}
```

My query didn't look right, '\v' was taken by the system as a value.
[view dump output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkZmL.png)

Adding another backslash to screen the one in '\v' solved this. The query worked after that, the error was gone.

```
$from = " FROM App\Vk\UsrBundle\Entity\\vUser u";
```

Not sure if this is the very same root cause you may have, but this may help to investigate.